# IterativeImputer - sample_posterior

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

Sklearn implements an imputer called the [IterativeImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.IterativeImputer.html). I believe that it works by predicting the values for missing features values in a round robin fashion, using an estimator.

It has an argument called sample_posterior but I can't seem to figure out when I should use it.

> sample_posterior boolean, default=False
>
> Whether to sample from the (Gaussian) predictive posterior of the fitted estimator for each imputation. Estimator must support
> return_std in its predict method if set to True. Set to True if using
> IterativeImputer for multiple imputations.

I looked at the source code but it still wasn't clear to me. Should I use this if I have multiple features that I am going to fill using the iterative imputer or should I use this if I plan to use the imputer multiple times like for a training and then validation set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with multiple features, and a training and validation/test set, you don't need `sample_posterior`.  The "multiple imputations" part of the docstring means generating more than one missings-replaced dataset; see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_%28statistics%29#Multiple_imputation).

Normally, `IterativeImputer` imputes the missing values of a feature using the predictions of a model built on the other features (iteratively, round robin, etc.).  If you use a model that produces not just a single prediction but an output *distribution* (the *posterior*), then you can sample from that distribution randomly, hence `sample_posterior`.  By running it multiple times, with different random seeds, these random choices are different, and you get multiple imputed datasets.
The documentation on that isn't great, but there's a (somewhat aged) [PR for an extended example](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/13025/files), and a [toy example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615845/10495893).

Comment: The PR link was helpful - and there's some more in the sklearn docs here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#multiple-vs-single-imputation